# How to find in one document on the basis of condition in the second document based on ref _Id mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

For instance

```
RecordSchema = {
user:{
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
transcations:[Object]
title:String
} 

UserSchema:{
name:String,
active:Boolean
}
```

I want to find all those record where user is active true

For instance

```
records = await Record.find({title:req.query.title}).populate('user).where(
user.active, true);
```

Comment: Why can't you just query the user schema?

Comment: I want to get records of only active users. I need records not users.

Comment: Have you tried `.populate()`? Plus I don't think MongoDB supports `.where()` like SQL DBs

Comment: Populate simply populate the user object instead of applying condition.

Comment: You have to populate first before applying conditions. Otherwise, it's just gonna be an ObjectId that's it.

Comment: I tried it but condition did not work